# How to split words in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

Good evening, People

Currently I have an Array called inputArray which stores an input file 7 lines line by line. I have a word which is `70000($s0)`, how do I split the word so it is 70000 & ($s0) separate?

I looked at an answer which is on this website already but I couldn't understand it the answer I looked at was:

```
s='1000($s3)'
IFS='()' read a b <<< "$s"
echo -e "a=<$a>\nb=<$b>"
```

giving the output `a=<1000> b=<$s3>`

Comment: You should add what you have already tried (i.e. your code)

Comment: Also *literal* input and *literal* output is always helpful.

Comment: Apologies i'm new to using bash i'm learning slowly

Comment: `IFS` is explained in the Bash manual … "input field separator…"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give this a shot.

In certain circumstances, the shell will perform "word splitting", where a string of text is broken up into words. The word boundaries are defined by the `IFS` variable. The default value of IFS is: space, tab, newline. When a string is to be split into words, any sequence of this set of characters is removes to extract the words.

In your example, the set of characters that delimit words are `(` and `)`. So the words in that string that are bounded by the IFS set of characters are `1000` and `$s3`

What is `<<< "$s"`? This is a here-string. It's used to send a string to some command's standard input. It's like doing

```
echo "$s" | read a b
```

except that form doesn't work as expected in bash. `read a b <<< "$s"` works well.

Now, what are the circumstances where word splitting occurs? One is when a variable is unquoted. A demo:

```
IFS='()'
echo "$s" | wc    # 1 line, 1 word and 10 characters
echo $s | wc      # 1 line, 2 words and 9 characters
```

The `read` command also splits a string into words, in order to assign words to the named variables. The variable `a` gets the first word, and `b` gets all the rest.

The command, broken down is:

```
  IFS='()' read a b <<< "$s"
# ^^^^^^^                      1
#                   ^^^^^^^^   2
#          ^^^^^^^^            3
```

1. only for the duration of the `read` command, assign the variable `IFS` the value `()`
2. send the string `"$s"` to `read`'s stdin
3. from stdin, use `$IFS` to split the input into words: assign the first word to variable `a` and the rest of the string to variable `b`. Trailing characters from `$IFS` at the end of the string are discarded.

Documentation:

- [Word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)
- [Here strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)
- [Simple command execution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Simple-Command-Expansion), describing why this assignment of IFS is only in effect for the duration of the read command.
- [`read` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read)

Hope that helps.